# How to combine 2 arrays and set the elements as variables?

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables, element

```
items = ["pickle", "tuna", "pasta_sauce", "beans", "soup"]
price = [6, 5, 3, 2, 2]
items = price
```

I'd like to be to call, for example: `pickle #=> 6; tuna # => 5` and so on.

Comment: It’s completely unclear what did you expect and _why_. Please specify the exact result you want to receive.

Comment: It's not possible to set local variables this way dynamically, I'd advice creating proper hash.

Comment: _"set the elements as variables?"_ – Don't do that, use a hash instead, i.e. `{ 'pickle' => 6, 'tuna' => 5, ... }`

Comment: Okay, Hashes might do the work! TY :D

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to dynamically create local variables.

You can do something like `eval "abc = 123; puts abc"` but after that `abc` is still undefined.

It is possible to change values of existing local variables:

```
items = ["pickle", "tuna", "pasta_sauce", "beans", "soup"]
price = [6, 5, 3, 2, 2]

pickle = nil
tuna = nil
pasta_sauce = nil
beans = nil
soup = nil

local_binding = binding
items.zip(price).each do |var, val|
  local_binding.local_variable_set var, val
end

puts pasta_sauce
# outputs 3
```

You probably want to do something different. You can for example dynamically create instance variables:

```
items = ["pickle", "tuna", "pasta_sauce", "beans", "soup"]
price = [6, 5, 3, 2, 2]

items.zip(price).each do |var, val|
  instance_variable_set "@#{var}", val
end

puts @pasta_sauce
# outputs 3
```

Comment: `to_h` is redundant in both places.

Comment: Using `#each_slice` after the `#zip` will not give you the correct result. In the first iteration `var` will be `["pickle", 6]` and `val` will be `["tuna", 5]`. Leave it out for a working answer.

Comment: True that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you'd be far better suited converting the two arrays to a hash to access, rather than using meta programming to set the variables (although @KimmoLehto provides a great answer should you choose that route).

As a much simpler way to create a hash of the two arrays:

```
my_hash = Hash[items.zip(price)]
# or
my_hash = items.zip(price).to_h
```

`items.zip(price)` combines the arrays (see: [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-zip)):

```
[["pickle", 6], ["tuna", 5], ["pasta_sauce", 3], ["beans", 2], ["soup", 2]]
```

And using [`Hash::[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) or [`to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) converts to a hash:

```
{"pickle"=>6, "tuna"=>5, "pasta_sauce"=>3, "beans"=>2, "soup"=>2}
```

You can then access the keys using the standard hash syntax:

```
my_hash['pickle'] # => 6
```

Or convert to and [`OpenStruct`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) if you prefer to access the variables using a `.`:

```
my_open_struct = OpenStruct.new(items.zip(price).to_h)
my_open_struct.pickle # => 6
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Keep in mind that [`Hash#symbolize_keys!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys-21) is part of the Rails "[activesupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport)" gem and this question is not tagged with `ruby-on-rails`

Comment: Argh you're right. Really had in mind that was core Ruby. Will remove that section, thanks @JohanWentholt.

Comment: Did this help at all @SavageHolycow?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new hash for aggregating those arrays.

```
items = ["pickle", "tuna", "pasta_sauce", "beans", "soup"]
price = [6, 5, 3, 2, 2]
hash = {} # or Hash.new

items.each_with_index do |var, idx|
  hash[var] = price[idx]
end

puts hash["pasta_sauce"] # 3
puts hash["pickle"] # 6
```

Comment: or `items.zip(price).to_h`.

Comment: Urgh just added that as an answer having now seen this comment @KimmoLehto :)